# How does nested powers work?

Tags: notation, big-bang, mathematics

Sir Roger Penrose has quantified the "very special" nature of the big bang as being "**1 part in 10 to the 10 to the 243**", but I do not understand what this really means - my apologies but I cannot even *write* the figure properly, either using notation, as my phone only copes with 1 line of superscript, or by employing solely regular numerals, as apparently even if I could fit each zero onto it's own proton there would still not be enough protons in the observable universe for me to complete it, (or have I misconstrued Sir Roger here? Presumably *he* at least understands the basics of scientific notation!)

Comment: Is your question what does something like '10 to the 10 to the 243' mean?

Comment: MathJax:  `$10^{10^{243}}$` yields $10^{10^{243}}$.

Comment: Yeah, that's not scientific notation. Just a power tower.

Comment: Indeed. You can interpret the number as '1 with $10^{243}$' zeros behind it, where $10^{243}$ is 1 with 243 zeros behind it. It's a very big number. E.g. even $10^{10^2}$ is 1,000,000,...[94 more zeros].

Answer (score 2):

You can interpret the number you mentioned, $10^{10^{243}}$, as '1 with $10^{243}$' zeros behind it, where $10^{243}$ is 1 with 243 zeros behind it. It's a very big number. E.g. even $10^{10^2}$ is 1,000,000,...[with 94 more zeros].